# ReactJs + React Router: re-rouse using keyboard events

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a simple PoC using ReactJs and React-Router, its gonna be shipping within an embedded webkit and the only controls available are (left, up, right, down and enter - basically only keyboard events).

Since I am not dealing with links, how could I activate an specific route when the user press enter?

Lets say its a TV app with multiple screens inside of it (guide, on demand, search, etc).

Thanks
T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [NavigationMixin](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Navigation) in your components to programatically transition to new routes.

```js
React.createClass({
  mixins: [NavigationMixin],

  _onEvent: function(e) {
    this.transitionTo(/* ... */);
  },

  render: function() { /* ... */ },
});
```